# How to do an =ANY(SELECT...query in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, array

I'm trying to select all the latitudes and longitudes for a group of users based on their id being in an array stored in another table. Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude 
FROM userloc WHERE id = ANY( SELECT interested FROM donedeals WHERE deals_id=67);
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
LINE 1: SELECT latitude, longitude FROM userloc WHERE id = ANY( SELE...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
       You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

`donedeals` has an `int` column for `deals_id` and an `int array` column for `interested`, which contains id's corresponding to the id column of `userloc`, which stores latitude and longitude:

```
 deals_id |  interested   
----------+---------------
       67 | {377,387,376}
       64 | {381,384}
       66 | {377,387}

  latitude  |  longitude  | id  
------------+-------------+-----
 40.6439417 |  -73.964927 | 384
 40.7554919 |  -73.925891 | 380
 40.6434067 | -73.9657654 | 385
  40.746452 |   -73.90732 | 378
  40.643459 |  -73.964586 | 381
 40.6430341 | -73.9656954 | 382
```

This is all in Postgres 9.3.5.

I'd like to select all latitudes and longitudes for id's corresponding to the `interested` array for a given `deals_id`. This seems like it should be doable in a single call, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately `= ANY (array)` only works with an array *literal* on the right hand side, not a sub-select.

You need to "normalize" your de-normalized model, using `unnest()`:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude 
FROM userloc 
WHERE id IN (SELECT unnest(interested) 
             FROM donedeals 
             WHERE deals_id = 64);
```

If `deals_id` is unique in the `donedeals` table, another option is to "convert" the `id` on the left side to an array and then use the "is contained by" operator: `<@`:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude 
FROM userloc 
WHERE array[id] <@ (SELECT interested 
                    FROM donedeals 
                    WHERE deals_id=64 );
```

Not sure which one would be faster. You will need to check the execution plan.

Comment: The 2nd query breaks if more than 1 row is returned from the subselect. Cannot happen as long as `deal_id` is unique, which seems like but hasn't been specified.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: you are absolutely right, thanks. I added that

Answer (score 4):

Typically, this whould better be rewritten as `JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.latitude, u.longitude 
FROM   userloc   u
JOIN   donedeals d ON u.id = ANY (d.interested)
WHERE  d.deals_id = 67;
```

I also considered the ["is contained by" operator: `<@`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html), that [@a_horse already mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90462/3684). It can use a GIN index on `interested`. But on a second look, that's irrelevant here. This query needs indexes on `userloc.id` and `donedeals.deals_id`.

Or with `unnest()` in a `LATERAL` join (Postgres **9.3+**):

```
SELECT u.latitude, u.longitude 
FROM   donedeals d
     , unnest(d.interested) i(id) -- implicit JOIN LATERAL
JOIN   userloc u ON u.id = i.id
WHERE  d.deals_id = 67;
```

The latter should be faster since it can use indexes on both `userloc.id` and `donedeals.deals_id`.

There is one possible difference: In your original, *distinct* rows are returned from `userloc` (which might still hold duplicate values for `(latitude, longitude)`). If (and only if) that is relevant:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.id)  -- id unique
       u.latitude, u.longitude 
FROM   ...
```

Or `GROUP BY u.id` with id being the PK.
You could also:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.latitude, u.longitude 
FROM   ...
```

That would *additionally* fold duplicates on `(latitude, longitude)`. It all depends on exact table definitions and requirements.

#### Alternative: normalize

Another option would be to [**normalize your schema**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), which would simplify the query to plain joins. Looks like a typical **many-to-many** relationship. Reference implementation:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)